# What is the meaning of expression "There's more fours than fives"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Does anyone know what this expression means? My father loaded trucks in the 1950s with a guy who said this.  The only explanation I ever got was that it was some kind of gay slur. But for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Context is essential to understanding meaning. *When* would he say it, i.e. to what event or statement would he be reacting?

Comment: Thanks!  -- I can try to get more context from my father, but his memory isn't the best anymore.  I got the impression it was said as a "sly" aside...wisdom being passed on to a younger guy.

Comment: It could refer to the [Enneagram personality types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneagram_of_Personality), but I don't know if these type numbers go back to the 50's. Fours are sensitive and introspective, fives are cerebral.